# Setting my C# application as a startup program

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm trying to make my C# project as a Click-once startup project but it doesn't read the folder directory can someone help me? This is my code.

```
private void SetStartUp()
    {
        string appName = "PMD Client";
        string publisherName = "Novus May";

        string startupPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
        startupPath = Path.Combine(startupPath, appName) + ".appref-ms";
        if (!File.Exists(startupPath))
        {
            string allProgramsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
            string shortcutPath = Path.Combine(allProgramsPath, publisherName);
            shortcutPath = Path.Combine(shortcutPath, appName) + ".appref-ms";
            File.Copy(shortcutPath, startupPath);
        }
    }
```

The error says System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:

Comment: I presume this is the problem: `allProgramsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)` Did you mean to use a different special folder?

Comment: @DStanley I'm trying get this path. --> C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\PMD Client.appref-ms

Comment: In a variable called `allProgramsPath `?

Comment: are u trying to copy file from C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\Novus May\\PMD Client.appref-ms to C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\PMD Client.appref-ms

Comment: whats the purpose of publisherName

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing seems a bit odd in the first place. Not sure you should do it like this. But with regards to your question, I am guessing you have added the path to startup erroneously for **shortcutPath**?

***Just set a breakpoint and step though it?***

```
File.Copy(shortcutPath, startupPath);
```

Values:

***shortcutPath***: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Novus May\PMD Client.appref-ms` (the **Startup** folder seems wrong).

***startupPath***: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\PMD Client.appref-ms`

> Maybe you want something like this instead? I have taken out the "Startup" folder:
>
> ***shortcutPath***: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\Novus May\PMD Client.appref-ms`